# ZipFile.extractall throws ZipFile instance has no attribute 'extractall'

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Following is my code:

```
import zipfile
from zipfile import ZipFile

def extract(zipFilename, dm_extraction_dir) :
   zipTest = ZipFile(zipFilename)
   zipTest.extractall(dm_extraction_dir)

extract("myzip.zip", "C:/Temp")
```

When I execute this code, throws ZipFile instance has no attribute 'extractall', I am using Python 2.5, interpreter is jython, not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall):

> *New in version 2.6.*